# ”e.g.“ and "i.e."

Tags: translation, grammar, word-choice

I'm working on a translation that requires an "e.g.".

For an example: "The way we cook food (e.g. baking or frying techniques) leads to different health consequences despite using he same ingredients." What would be the best way, in your opinion?

Something like "做饭的方式（像烘焙或油炸）发生不同的健康后果。" comes to my mind, bit is that professional/correct?

Comment: 譬如 or 例如 are good replacements. They mean "for example". They're quite useful expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your example in brackets in the middle of your sentence, it's perfectly enough to use only 例.

...（例烘焙或油炸）...

Here 例 stands as an abbreviation for 例如, and as a single character comes close to 'e.g.' or i.e. than the full expression. I see that everybody comes up with 例如, but that's not an abbreviation, so it corresponds more to the full expression "for example", than "e.g.".

Actually, you can also use 如 as a single character the same way. Here are two example usages for both characters in the same [Wikipedia article](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E9%90%B5%E9%81%93%E8%BF%B7#.E5.88.86.E9.A1.9E) *(scroll down a bit to get to them)*:

- 训练用之铁路模拟器（**例**：日本埼玉县的铁路博物馆中的铁路模拟驾驶台馆藏，与JR训练用之模拟驾驶台大致相同）
- 铁路车辆（**如**：冷气平快车）

As for the colon (冒号), it is not necessary to use.

Answer (score 1):

同樣的材料用不同的料理方式（例如烘培或油炸），對健康有不同的影響

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you replace 发生 with 会导致

Translate e.g. to 像 is fine. You can use 譬如, 例如, 诸如, etc.

i.e. = 即, 就是, etc.

Comment: 例如 is right on spot i think, +1

Comment: i。e。iciba：abbr.
(=id est) <拉>即，换言之；